# Windows IIS Rewrite URL

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting

I have a page located at 'ourdomain/FolderName/ourpage' and have a redirect set up so that users can go to the link 'ourdomain/ourpage' and have it link to it. This works fine, however the URL bar still displays the long ugly 'ourdomain/FolderName/ourpage'.

I have the following URL Rewrite rule set up, however it seems to be doing nothing at all, the long link remains after hard-refreshing and restarting the web server. Do I have something set up incorrectly? (edited the real folder/page names out in screenshot for privacy sake)

[URL Rewrite configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RS5a2.png)

Comment: Mistake 1 https://halfblood.pro/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59

Answer (score 0):

The pattern for the url rewrite shouldn't include the domain name.

The  pattern should only be the url's path and shouldn't include the domain name.

The url rewrite rule should like below

Please modify the pattern part to `ourdomain/FolderName/ourpage` and test again.